# Parsing multi part form data with Busyboy getting objects in a weird format

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data, netlify-function

Unable to parse multipart form data as the return data from Busyboy is in some weird format. I can see the correct values in the terminal however it contains some symbols so couldn't JSON.parse it.

```
JSON.parse(fields.values)
```

Does anyone know which format this is and how to parse it?

Just couldn't understand what format it is.

Any help appreciated.

**[image: weird format]**

```
function parseMultipartForm(event) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        // we'll store all form fields inside of this
        const fields = {};
    
        // let's instantiate our busboy instance!
        const busboy = new Busboy({
          // it uses request headers
          // to extract the form boundary value (the ----WebKitFormBoundary thing)
          headers: event.headers
        });
    
        // before parsing anything, we need to set up some handlers.
        // whenever busboy comes across a file ...
        busboy.on(
          "file",
          (fieldname, filestream, filename, transferEncoding, mimeType) => {
            // ... we take a look at the file's data ...
            filestream.on("data", (data) => {
              // ... and write the file's name, type and content into `fields`.
              fields\[fieldname\] = {
                filename,
                type: mimeType,
                content: data,
              };
            });
          }
        );
    
        // whenever busboy comes across a normal field ...
        busboy.on("field", (fieldName, value) => {
          // ... we write its value into `fields`.
          fields\[fieldName\] = value;
        });
    
        // once busboy is finished, we resolve the promise with the resulted fields.
        busboy.on("finish", () => {
          resolve(fields)
        });
    
        // now that all handlers are set up, we can finally start processing our request!
        busboy.write(event.body);
      });
    }
    
    exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    
      const fields = await parseMultipartForm(event)
    
      console.log(fields)
    
    }
```

Comment: Is pdf file working for you???

Comment: Follow this -> https://www.netlify.com/blog/2021/07/29/how-to-process-multipart-form-data-with-a-netlify-function/